# Google Play Console - Will promoting a release to Production invalidate an Open Testing track?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

By mistake I created an **Open Testing** release instead of a **Production** release. They are not still sent to review. This is the current *Publishing Overview*:

[image: Current Publishing Overview]

Is there any way to remove the **Open Testing** one ? At this moment this track is paused so it wont be public. If finally I cannot remove it, will be automatically published or it will still keep closed.

What would happen if I upload a build with higher version into the **Open Testing** and then promote it to **Production**. Will it remove/close the **Open Testing** ?

I've gone through all the documentation and I cannot find any information about how to remove/close an **Open Testing**